# jquery Object Iteration with Alert

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain how to iterate through all my object values with an alert?

```
// get a single audio url
echonest.artist("Prince").audio(function(audioCollection) {    
    $('#artistAudioURL').append(audioCollection.data.audio[0].url);         
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, at least in the sense that it doesn't seem to have anything at all to do with the code snippet you posted.

Comment: What are `artist()` and `audio()`?

Comment: audio[x] contains all my values. I need to learn how to trigger an alert for each one. Audio() is a function in a plugin i am using. Same for Artist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With which object do need to iterate ?
jQuery method for iterate is `$(obeject).each( function() {} )`